# mvc route problem - using integer parameters

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing

I have a route like this in my `global.asax.cs`:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           "NewsArticles",
           "News/{page}",
           new { controller = "News", action = "Index", archive = false }
       );
```

How can I restrict access to this route so that it's only encountered if  the user uses an integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you put this route before the default route. You could also use regular expressions to restrict possible parameter values:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "NewsArticles",
    "News/{page}",
    new { controller = "News", action = "Index" },
    new { page = @"^\d{1,3}$" }
);
```

Remark: In your example you are using `archive = false` while there is no `archive` parameter defined in the route.